# Runtime error when trying to send bitcoins

Tags: sending

When sending coins, an error message pops up saying: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way, please contact it the applications support team", what do?

Comment: This error usually indicates that one or more files which Bitcoin relies upon have become corrupted. A good first troubleshooting step would be to delete everything **except wallet.dat** in your %appdata%\Roaming\Bitcoin folder and allow Bitcoin to re-download the block chain. It would also be helpful to know if your installation has ever worked and if so, what has changed.

Comment: Tried redownloading the block chain, it didn't work. It used to work however, i have both sent and recieved coins before. The only difference I can think of is that i forgot my pass, and did several failed attempts (like 150) before i got it right, i had forgotten the last two digits

Comment: Okay, tried switching pass now as well - got the same error. So the problem seems to be connected to the password and the lock on the wallet

Comment: If your wallet has become corrupted you might be able to recover the private keys using something like pywallet and then restore them to a blank wallet.